# Debug do NodeJS utilizando visual studio code

Tags: node.js, debug

Estou usando o Visual Studio Code e não estou conseguindo debugar um nodejs por ele.

Se eu colocar um *breakpoint* em qualquer lugar do meu app.js e iniciar o debug, ele funciona, mas quando eu já tenho ele no browser e for mudar para uma outra rota, por exemplo, nada acontece.
Atualizando a página sendo que ele fica na rota root (/), também nada acontece.
Ele só é acionado na primeira vez.

Estou começando agora a utilizar o nodejs + visual studio code e gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me orientar e explicar como funciona o debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei descobrindo que eu estava colocando o *breakpoint* no lugar errado, fazendo com que não fosse acionado utilizando o Visual Studio Code.

Eu também testei o debug do Visual Studio Community 2015 com suporte a Nodejs e me pareceu uma ótima opção de uso para programar.

Dessa forma, considero minha dúvida sanada.

Answer (score -1):

Se quiser uma soluçao com node faça o seguinte, coloque debugger, em trechos do código e no terminal do vscode digite o commando:

node inspect nomedoarquivo.js

0

function facaalgumacoisa(a+b) {

debugger;

return a+b;
}

let test = 0;

debugger;